# Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent

Tags: jquery, variables, iframe

How can I work with jQuery and `iframe`. Get and pass `var` from `iframe` to `body` and from `body` to `iframe`. I have the following example. How can I click the button in `iframe` and make it take effect on the the `body` `#test`. How about ready var x in iframe.

```
<body>
var x = "whatever";
<div id"test"></div>
<iframe width="200px" height="200px" src="page.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Inside page.html i have

```
<button>clickme</button>
<script>
var elm = $('<span>content</span>');
    elm.appendTo('#test')
</script>
```

Comment: Note that most browsers will only allow manipulation of the parent document from within an iframe when both documents are from the exact same domain, as per the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @tdammers - Thats a good point.

Comment: Yes. Bit me once. I had this wonderful script that would adjust the height of an iframe to its content, but it only worked on the test rig, where both pages were served from localhost :-(

Comment: can anyone tell me that how pass value dynamically of src ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$("#myid", top.document);
```

or

```
$("#myid", parent.document.body);
```

This will give you access to the container of the IFRAME

as per : http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/5997ef4a60a123af

Comment: Ive used it in the past. Can you update your question to include your new code then?

Comment: Note, that the frames must be in the same origin for this to work.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 14):

From the parents perspective:

```
var iFrameValue = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.myLocalFunction();
```

OR

```
var iFrameValue = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.myLocalVariable;
```

From the iframe perspective

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myLocalVariable = "hello";

function myLocalFunction () {
    return "hello";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contentWindow` and `contentDocument` properties, if [same origin poilicy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is not a problem. I've setup a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/uGjTq/show/). View [code for the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/uGjTq/) and [code for iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/USWrV/).