# from jquery to page variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Please forgive my poor use of the correct terminology here!

I have a page with nested iframe where I use jquery to traverse through to it - I can pull any element from the iframe and perform jquery functions on it.

Within the iframe's page, is a javascript variable.  How can I access this variable?

cheers :)

Comment: Does the content of the iframe come from the same domain as that of the container page?

Comment: not exacly what you are looking for - but close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

Comment: perfect, cheers.. (and thanks to everyone else for the other responses).. I guess wanting to do the 'finding' through jQuery was a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your iframes are hosted on the same domain you can access them from the window.frames array.  Something so:

```
window.frames['myframename'].document.some_variable
```

Comment: Variable can be accessed through `window` object, not `document`.