# Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent in opera

Tags: jquery, variables, iframe

this problem is solved here: [Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent)

Anyway, this wont work on opera. It's fine on firefox, but opera gives me this error:

Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable

I need to pass variables between iframe and parent and it's enough for me if this works only in recent major browsers releases.

Comment: If both the iframe and the parent page reside in the same domain then talking between the two can be done bottom-up by calling parent.functionName() within the child. Otherwise you will not have visibility.

Comment: Yes, iframe and parent is in the same domain, and parent.functionName() not working on Opera, same error, but work fine with firefox5 and chrome.

Comment: Currently im working on localhost and this part of url address are the same: http://127.0.0.1/www/cms/admin/

Comment: **This is in the iframe:** 

`$('#close').click(function(){
    parent.iframeCatch();
})`

**And this is in the parent:**

`function iframeCatch() {
 $('iframe#media').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 500, function() { $(this).detach(); });
 console.log('Ok, I\'m officially On now!')
}`

Comment: Unfortunately I just noticed that my tiny MCE editor stopped working properly in Opera too. Opera loads the editor, but not allowed to select textarea and write something. I got error similar to what I get from iframe: `Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: open` In other browsers like firefox or chrome everything works fine. Is there is some bug with opera and iframes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent)