# change jquery current tab on button click from a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a `iframe` in one of the `jQuery ui tabs` opened which has a `button` on click of which i need to switch to another tab

I tried using

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , 1 )
```

But it seems that I can not access the tabs outside iframe

Comment: You should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
window.parent.$("#tabs").tabs("select",1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your function to look at the parent of the iframe

```
$("#tabs", parent.document.body).tabs( "select" , 1 );
```