# How to Remove a iframe by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a `iframe` in a `div` by jQuery.Then I load another page(lets say page A.jsp) into that iframe. The page 'A.jsp' has some functionality and end of it, the parent iframe should be removed from the first page when a button in 'A.jsp' is pressed .  Loading the page 'A.jsp' into the iframe is OK. but I can't remove the parent iframe. How I tried was, select the parent tag `iframe` then, remove it. but it didn't work. Here is how I tried.Here $(this) referes to a button in page A.jsp and &('div iframe')referes to the parent iframe

```
$(this).closest($('div iframe')) .animate({
                                   opacity:0
                               },500,function(){$(this).remove()})
```

How can I remove the parent iframe ?

Comment: Could you not create a function on the main page to do it and then call it from the within the iframe?

Comment: what is "this" ? from where are you calling that function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the info you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689154/897871

Note: the page that hosts the iframe and the page with the content will have to reside on the same host.

Comment: Yes, $("#myid", top.document); is the code. my id is something in the parent page and top.document says to select from top document. Here it describes more http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/5997ef4a60a123af?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

To which element does `this` refer to?

To access the iframe you should point to:

```
parent.document
```

or

```
parent.$("iframe")
```

if you want to use jQuery. 
Same Origin Policy is always involved here, so pay attention to what you can actually do.

Another solution is to reload the parent page using a simple link that has `target="_parent"`.

see also here:

[How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The iframe can be fully remove from the DOM by the remove method 
eg

This is my iframe

```
<div id="videoPlayerOP" > <iframe id="optionsPlayVideo" width="520" height="348" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 7px;" src="about:blank"></iframe></div>
```

After loading some source in it, It can be remove by

```
$($("#optionsPlayVideo").parent()).empty();
```

If you want to reuse them them append another iframe in it

```
$('#videoPlayerOP').append('<iframe id="optionsPlayVideo" width="520" height="348" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 7px;" src="about:blank"></iframe>');
```

Thanks