# Using <iframe> to add one HTML page to another, how to give effects on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use `<iframe>` within another page.

How can I give effects to the controls of first HTML page *id's* or *classes*, while accessing it from a second page?

Comment: are you using some javascript framework like JQuery?

Comment: yes I sm using Jquery 1.9.1.

Comment: Are the documents on the same domain?

Comment: both documents are in same domain

Comment: You change the URL of the iframe when some button is clicked? is only one iframe? If you want to add some effects to the elements insed of the iFrame see this answer : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[something like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent)

use

```
$("#myid", top.document);
```

or

```
$("#myid", parent.document.body);
```