# How to access frames in a parent window in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS calls in a popup that update the state of frame elements in a parent window,  that I would like to replace with jQuery calls:

parent.window.opener.parent.frames[0].someCustomFunction();
parent.window.opener.parent.frames[1].document.getElementById('text').value = "some text";

What is the best way to access the these in a parent?

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass jquery variables between iframe and parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent)

Comment: I need to be able to access frames in the parent rather then an Iframe. Also how do I call the someCustomFunction() function in the first frame from the popup?

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery, just give a name to `frame` elements, then you can use the name to refer the window object of a frame. For example in your case:

```
window.opener.frame_name.someCustomFunction();
```

When you've the `name` attribute set, you can also refer a frame from another frame using `top` property of the `window` object, for example:

```
var doc = top.frame_name.document;
```