# Load the response into iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can anyone help me to load response in to iframe using JQuery.
I tried following ways.

```
$.post(url, $("formid").serialize(), function(data) {
$("#myIframe").contents().html(data);
})
```

I dont want to do

```
$(".myIframe").attr('src', "myServlet/"+encodedParam);
```

Because this will expose the data.And also in ie unable to load window with url having than 2038 characters.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent

Answer (score 1):

try to use `$("#myIframe").contents().find('html').html(data);`

Comment: This works even when the iframe is empty like this: <iframe></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframe = $("#Iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
                iframe.open(); 
                iframe.write(data);
                iframe.close();
```

This solution worked for me
Thanks a lot for responding:)